# Office Addin - programmatically import *.exportedUI settings file

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ms-office

Is it possible to import existing `*.exportedUI` file on the Addin start up?

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't any import functionality.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b2830e72-9f78-4d4d-8f39-af14bfb991c8/office-addin-programmatically-import-exportedui-settings-file